# React checkboxes don't reset after submitting form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to React, so I decided to make a skincare app to learn the beast. I thus made a form to register the products, and this form contains checkboxes. My problem is, I cannot for the life of me get them to reset (empty?) after submitting the form. All the answers I've found were either too old or didn't work.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./ProductForm.module.css";

const ProductForm = (props) => {

//Frequency checkboxes handler functions
  const [isDayChecked, setDayChecking] = useState([]);

  const dayFrequencyHandler = (event) => {
    const { value, checked } = event.target;
    // Case 1 : The user checks the box
    if (checked) {
      setDayChecking((checkedDays) => [...checkedDays, value]);
    }
    // Case 2  : The user unchecks the box
    else {
      setDayChecking(isDayChecked.filter((e) => e !== value));
    }
  };

  const [isNightChecked, setNightChecking] = useState([]);

  const nightFrequencyHandler = (event) => {
    const { value, checked } = event.target;
    // Case 1 : The user checks the box
    if (checked) {
      setNightChecking((checkedNights) => [...checkedNights, value]);
    }
    // Case 2  : The user unchecks the box
    else {
      setNightChecking(isNightChecked.filter((e) => e !== value));
    }
  };

//Submission function
const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
//Save data from the inputs
    const savedProductData = {
      isDayChecked: isDayChecked,
      isNightChecked: isNightChecked,
    };

//Reset the inputs after submit
    setDayChecking([]);
    setNightChecking([]); 
}
return (
//JSX code for checkboxes inputs (day and night)
<form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <label>Frequency</label>
      <p>M</p>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="Monday"
        name="day"
        onChange={dayFrequencyHandler}
      />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="Monday-night"
        name="night"
        onChange={nightFrequencyHandler}
      />
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
 );
}

export default ProductForm;
```

As you can see, these checkboxes are used to register at what frequency the products are going to be used (one checkbox for the morning and one for the night, for each day of the week). The data is then stored into the empty array of useState(), or removed when the user unchecks its box. That part works fine.

What doesn't work fine though, is my submit function that refuses to clear the checkboxes once called. The most logical solution to me would be to reset the checkboxes' state to their original, well, state of empty arrays, like this:

```
const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    setDayChecking([]);
    setNightChecking([]); 
  };
```

React obviously disagrees, since it doesn't work. The checkboxes are still checked on the form even after I submitted it. But if I call my submit function again (aka re-click on the submit button without checking anything again) without touching anything, the data (`savedProductData`)I console-logged tells me my checkboxes states are indeed set back to empty arrays. So clearly there isn't any data left in my state arrays once I've submitted the form. Yet the checkboxes still appear checked instead of being cleared out.

I guess my question would be, why don't the checkboxes appearing on the screen automatically clear when I submit my form and their states are back to empty arrays? And how do I get them to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "React disagrees" and "it's even worse" in what ways specifically? Can you share a [mcve] with your rendering JSX and component header? Thanks.

Comment: "React disagrees" because it just doesn't work, it's like I didn't add anything and the "it's even worse" is just me being dramatic. It doesn't work either though.

I guess I can edit my post with my jsx code and my submit function?

Comment: Ok, I think I explained the problem a little bit better (edited the original post). Thanks for being patient with me. I hope the issue is clearer now.

Comment: Much clearer, thanks. Final tip would be to put all of your code into a single, complete block, with a component header and imports. This way, I can run it easily and instantly see the problem instead of figuring out how the pieces should be glued together.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the delay, got kinda busy. So I put everything in one block like you asked, and I also cleaned up a bit since the rest wasn't really relevant (worked well).

Answer (score 0):

Here is fully working example of how to use `checkbox`. Understand the underlying concepts and write similar components. You cannot say `checked={arrayData.includes(true)}`. It is not wrong in javascript. But imagine if you have more than two value in array and we are gonna map it in React. For example, your array is `[true, false, true, true, false]`. Checkbox should not have two same value data and you should not pass `boolean` value to checkbox. In your question, you did not provide your array's data types. In my example, it is `string` and there is no same data.

```
const App = () => {
  const arrayData = ["1", "two", "not boolean", "something more", "and more"];
  const [myArray, setMyArray] = React.useState([]);

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do submit
    setMyArray([]);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    e.target.checked
      ? setMyArray([...myArray, e.target.value])
      : setMyArray(myArray.filter((o) => o != e.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      {arrayData.map((item) => (
        <label key={item}>
          <input
            value={item}
            onChange={onChange}
            checked={myArray.includes(item)}
            type={"checkbox"}
          />
          <span>{item}</span>
        </label>
      ))}
      <input type={"submit"} />
    </form>
  );
};
export default App;
```

If you don't have array and you want to use `checkbox` with `boolean` value. Here it is.

```
const App = () => {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = React.useState(false);

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do submit
    setShowPassword(false);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setShowPassword(e.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      
        <label>
          <input
            onChange={onChange}
            checked={showPassword}
            type={"checkbox"}
          />
          <span>Show Password</span>
        </label>
      <input type={"submit"} />
    </form>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I've tried to add 
`checked={setDayChecking.includes(true)}`
and the console tells me that "setDayChecking.includes is not a function". Thanks for answering though!

Comment: I did not say anything about `setDayChecking`. `setDayChecking` is not array. I thought I would not need to explain in details. Sorry. My bad. `const [state,setState] = useState([some example array here])`. In this code, `state` is array. `setState` is not and `setState.includes` is not a function.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you made a typo and referring to setDayChecking, since the names are similar. What are you referring then, when you write "dayChecking"? Do you mean "isDayChecked"? Because this doesn't work either, and I have nothing in my code named "dayChecking".

Comment: To be more specific, I wrote `checked={isDayChecked.includes(false)}` (false because I didn't want to have it checked by default), and it just makes it impossible to check the box.